# Fast integer division in Java

Tags: java, performance, division, integer-division

It is well known that integer division is slow operation (typically several times slower than integer multiplication). But, if one need to perform many divide operations with a fixed divisor, it is possible to do some preconditioning on the divisor and replace "/" with multiplication and bit operations (Chapter 10 in [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org)).

As I've tested, if the divisor is a compilation-time constant, (e.g. `static final long DIVISOR = 12345L;`) JVM will do the trick and replace all divisions by `DIVISOR` with multiplication and bit operations. I'm interesting in the same kind of trick but when the divisor is known only at runtime.

For example, the following (slow) method:

```
void reduceArraySlow(long[] data, long denominator){
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
        data[i] = data[i] / denominator;
}
```

can be replaced with something:

```
void reduceArrayFast(long[] data, long denominator){
    SomeMagicStructure magic = computeMagic(denominator);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
         // computes data[i] / denominator
        data[i] = doFastDivision(data[i], magic);
}
```

which must do the job much faster, since all `/` operations are replaced with faster operations (and also because division is not pipelined in CPUs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is well known C/C++ [libdivide](http://libdivide.com) library for fast integer division, and there is my adaptation of this library for Java [libdivide4j](https://github.com/PoslavskySV/libdivide4j).

Fast division with libdivide4j looks as follows:

```
void reduceArrayFast(long[] data, long denominator){
    FastDivision.Magic magic = FastDivision.magicSigned(denominator);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
        // computes data[i] / denominator
        data[i] = FastDivision.divideSignedFast(data[i], magic);
}
```

A simple benchmark

```
public void benchmark() throws Exception {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int nIterations = 10000;
    //let the JIT to optimize something
    for (int att = 0; att < nIterations; att++) {
        long[] data = new long[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i] = rnd.nextLong();

        long denominator = rnd.nextLong();

        long[] slow = data.clone();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        reduceArraySlow(slow, denominator);
        long slowTime = System.nanoTime() - start;


        long[] fast = data.clone();
        start = System.nanoTime();
        reduceArrayFast(fast, denominator);
        long fastTime = System.nanoTime() - start;

        Assert.assertArrayEquals(slow, fast);

        // print last 100 timings (JVM already warmed up)
        if (att > nIterations - 100) {
            System.out.println("\"/\" operation: " + slowTime);
            System.out.println("Fast division: " + fastTime);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

shows the following timings (nanoseconds) for ordinary `/` and fast division (Core i7, jdk8 64-bit) :

```
"/" operation: 13233
Fast division: 5957

"/" operation: 13148
Fast division: 5103

"/" operation: 13587
Fast division: 6188

"/" operation: 14173
Fast division: 6773
...
```